# WiFi disconnects when VPN is running - how to troubleshoot?

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, vpn

I have a VPN (HMA pro) which is working fine on all but one device in one particular location. This device (a windows 8 laptop) used to work fine but lately after the VPN is connected, within a few minutes the WiFi disconnects. This only happens at one location - elsewhere it is fine. Other devices (another windows 8 laptop, and an android phone) can use the VPN over this WiFi without any problem, so it seems to be something specific to this one laptop and this one WiFi combination.

How can I troubleshoot this ?

---

Edit: 
Immediately after the WiFi disconnects, I found the following in the System event log:

```
(information)
The browser has forced an election on network \Device\NetBT_Tcpip_{57AF72D3-A630-421E-B170-9910E516A2A7} because a master browser was stopped.

(warning)
Name resolution for the name client.wns.windows.com timed out after none of the configured DNS servers responded.
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/fa4f80fe-1264-4f82-9132-a74e8c208c51#f90fcf8b-04ca-4bde-9b47-5e9fc65b26a7) help? Particularly the gateway setting. Also, I'm not too familiar with Windows 8, but perhaps the root cause is a power management issue? I wonder if it turns off wifi if you're not using the gateway. You could try checking your power management settings and also not allowing it to power off the wifi (via device manager). Does it happen when the laptop is plugged into AC power?

Comment: @JasonC  whoops - excuse me for that.  Umm, I can't see anyn option for default gateway. I have Network->VPN then I can choose the VPN name and select "Edit" but there isn't an option for default gateway

Comment: Ah, yeah it appears HMA Pro [doesn't seem to have](https://support.hidemyass.com/hc/en-us/articles/202724006-HMA-Pro-VPN-client-How-to-download-install-and-use#Instructionabouthmaprovpnclient) any equivalent options. Just out of curiosity, if you switch your laptop's power plan to High/Maximum Performance, does the problem go away?

Comment: @JasonC I've got 2 power options: Balanced and Power4Gear High Performance - it's on the latter ......

Comment: Is there anything in the event logs? Control Panel (on Window 8 move mouse to bottom left of desktop view and right click) -> Administrative Tools -> Event Viewer, look for relevant warnings or errors in Windows Logs -> Application or System around the time the wifi goes out.

Comment: Hmm, pretty much every Google search for [that message](https://www.google.com/search?q=the%20browser%20has%20forced%20an%20election%20on%20network%20because%20a%20master%20browser%20was%20stopped) leads to power-management related issues. Go to Control Panel -> Device Manager, find the wifi adapter, open its properties and uncheck "Allow the computer to turn this device off to save power". Does that resolve the issue?

Comment: @JasonC  no that didn't affect it. I can use the VPN over a different WiFi connection with no trouble ......